# dselect: the access method area is already locked

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I've installed dselect from source for fun and I'm receiving error

dselect: the access method area is already locked, when I select option 0 (access) or option 1 (update) from dselect main menu.

I've tried deleting the lock file from /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg and from /var/lib/dpkg but still receiving same the message.

Comment: It's possible your system was just trying to update itself (using `apt` type tools which are in the same family) so I'd suggest just being patient.   However installed from source (as in tarball? with make; make install..) as the /usr/local/var.. directory seems wrong to me (and could be because you made your own from source & thus use a different file as lock). I installed `dselect` (using `apt`) & didn't have issues but I've not used it in a lot of years so will have forgotten its idiosyncrasies...

Comment: it was a tarball in /usr/local/src with checkinstall